# How do I add members in Trello with read-only access?

Tags: trello

Is there a way for me to add Trello members with read-only access? Some users need to have access to see a board but not edit it.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this currently is by adding those users to an organization, then setting the visibility of the board to 'organization'. You can allow special privileges on the board (like voting and comments) to organization members, or just allow read-only access. Those users can get to the board via the organization profile.

You can also make the board public, but that doesn't sound like what you want.